# Does quagga support cross-platform routing? (linux distros)

Tags: routing, router, quagga

I have one Quagga router running on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr and I'm planning to install Lubuntu on a old laptop to turn it into a router. Will they ping each other? Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues, as long as you connect and configure the Quagga correctly.

Comment: Yes. They should ping each other even before you have Quagga installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can. As Everton mentioned they can already do so even before/during the installation. 
Quagga is a software on top of a linux/unix kernel. Much the same as, let's say, Firefox on top of Windows.

You can install Firefox on Windows on one machine and install Chrome on Linux on another machine. Regardless, the two machines are able to talk to each other on a TCP/IP level (ping each other) long before the browsers are installed. The network configuration is done long before Firefox or Chrome are ever installed. You need of course to configure it according to normal network standards, so they must be in the same subnet or have the correct router configured.

If you're asking whether they can exchange information other than ICMP pings, that depends primarily on software configuration and your Lubuntu installation. Debian/Ubuntu/Lubuntu also has similar software for OSPF, RIP and BGP servers, that you can install. Then they would be able to exchange routing information to each other.

For example you can install an OSPF daemon on your Lubuntu that exchanges routing information with your Quagga OSPF daemon.
Each individual program will be able to communicate with it's counterpart on the other machine. (for example BGP->BGP daemon, OSPF->OSPF daemon)

Answer (score 7):

Routing and network protocols are standardized. The Internet is vast heterogeneous network using routers, switches, servers, clients, etc. from many different vendors. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: "Why would you think otherwise?" - Why would you not think otherwise? (assuming you didn't already know the answer)

Comment: If you actually thought about it, you would realize that you have your Dell Windows 7 laptop, connected to your Homebrew Quagga Linux router, which connects to your ISP's Juniper equipment, which connects through its network to a peer which has Cisco gear, etc.

Comment: (Again, assuming you didn't already know the answer) you might assume that your laptop is specifically designed to talk directly to home routers, and your ISP-provided home router is designed to talk to whatever your ISP uses, and your ISP could well have special firmware or configuration on some of their devices to allow them to talk to each other.

Comment: Since "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._", and questions involving home networking are specifically off-topic, based on your comment, I would assume that you are somehow in the wrong site. You should probably ask your questions on [su].

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question. I'm pointing out that it's quite reasonable for someone to think otherwise (if they aren't a professional network engineer).

Comment: "_if they aren't a professional network engineer_" Then this would probably be be the wrong site.